# :dependent => :destroy for a serialized array value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have two models,

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :user_ids, Array
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Assume, user_ids in event model has a value [1,2,3,4].

Now, if I delete a user record with the ID 1.

It also has to delete the user_id resided in event table's user_ids field. the result should be `user_ids = [2,3,4]`. Like *:dependant => :destroy.*

Should I need need to write before_destroy callback for this for sure..?? or any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you suggested, you're going to have to do this in a callback you write yourself. Something like:

```
before_destroy :remove_users

def remove_users
  User.where(id: self.user_ids).destroy_all
end
```

It does look quite destructive though. Typically `User` is used for users who log into your system but I guess you're not using it like that in this case.

Comment: Thanks @shadwell., But is there any other simplest solution something like :dependant => :destroy instead of writing our own method for this scenario..? Sorry for the silly question.  :P :P

Comment: No, unfortunately, you're going to have to write your own code on this one - it's not a case that is supported by rails/active record.

Comment: Cool.. Thnaks.. :) :)\